# TypeScript and type aliases

Tags: javascript, typescript

As I know TypeScript allows to create aliases for any types. Such as:

```
type MyNum = number;
var y: MyNum;
y = 33; // it's ok
```

but the followong code is not valid:

```
type MyType = Object;
const dt = new MyType(); // here is an error: 'MyType only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here'
```

Where am I wrong and how could I create instance of MyType?

Comment: `const dt : MyType = {}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type aliases are only for compile time, they are not getting translated into the compiled javascript code.

Your first code compiles to:

```
var y;
y = 33;
```

As you can see, there's nothing here about `MyNum`.

However, in your 2nd code snippet you're trying to use `MyType` as a value and not just as a type.
The compiler won't allow that because at runtime `MyType` isn't present as it compiles to:

```
var dt = new MyType();
```

Type aliases, just like interfaces (and types in general) are used for compilation only, so you cannot use them as values.

---

#### Edit

To create an instance of `MyType`, in this case:

```
const dt1: MyType = {};
const dt2: MyType = new Object();
const dt3: MyType = Object.create({});
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what the OP should do instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sure thing. Thanks